# What is the proper way to check for existence of objects in Rails / Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a lot of models and relations. Due to this fact, there is lot of calls in views/controllers, which look like this:

```
 @object.something.with_something.value
```

Some part of the chain can end up being nil, which is perfectly ok. What is the proper/clean/fast way to check for the existence of the terminal object?

Is calling something like:

```
 @object.something.with_something.value if defined? @object.something.with_something.value
```

Considered ok?

Comment: This question isn't really worded very clearly... Do you only care about `@object.something.with_something.value` being `nil` or are you worried about the `NoMethodError` that gets raise if anything in the chain is `nil`?  I assume the latter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Natively, you'd need to use the `&&` operator (not `defined?`), but this can get very verbose, very quickly.

So instead of doing this:

```
(@object && @object.something && @object.something.with_something &&
  @object.something.with_something.value)
```

You can do this when ActiveSupport is present:

```
@object.try(:something).try(:with_something).try(:value)
```

Or install the [invocation construction kit](http://ick.rubyforge.org/) and use its guarded evaluation tools:

```
Ick::Maybe.belongs_to YourClass
maybe(@object) { |obj| obj.something.with_something.value }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's best to arrange the rest of your code in order to see this problem for at most the last object in a chain.

`defined?` won't do what you want. Something can be `defined?` and `nil` at the same time.

When the problem is restricted to the last attribute in a chain of references:

```
@object.something.with_something.value if @object.something.with_something
```

I might take advantage of the facts that:

```
nil.to_a => []
nil.to_s => ''
nil.to_f => 0.0
nil.to_i => 0
```

So, if you know that something is either `nil` or an `Array`, often you can write better code *without any conditionals* at all by writing something like:

```
something.to_a.each do |e|
  . . .
```

Comment: Yup, I reread the OP and figured out what you meant.  I read a bit into the OP's question because I knew the question I answered was more likely to have been the trouble he actually ran into.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not a really big fan of your solution though.  I've seen it come up a few times, and I remove it whenever I see it because I feel pretty strongly that it makes the code less readable.  Other methods like `try` and `maybe` solve the problem more generally and do so in a more readable way.

Comment: I know what you mean, but when I found out that `nil` had specialized `Object`'s to_*x* functions I thought: *Matz is really a genius.*  For example, **(something.somethingelse || []).each do** is really kind of clunky by comparison.

Answer (score 2):

`what.you.are.doing` is sometimes called a "Train wreck". It's also described as a violation of the Law of Demeter.

That being said, I think there's something called "andand" that can help with what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah, `Object#andand` is one solution, but I try to avoid it — it's kinda weird to introduce a dependency that essentially gives you one method.  Also, it monkey-patches the `Object` class by default, which is awful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) to ensure that none of those objects is ever nil. Arguably, if your code is going to chain access in that way, then *something* should always be defined.

Comment: The best part about this is that in Ruby, this pattern can effectively be implemented transparently.  That's essentially how the invocation construction kit implements `maybe` under the hood.  It provides an `IdentityWrapper` and a `GuardWrapper`.  The `GuardWrapper` has essentially the same purpose as a null object in that pattern, except that the wrapper can be automatically stripped off when the block evaluation completes.